# Range selector / range seekbar to trim video including thumbnails

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar, video-editing, video-thumbnails

[image]

I am looking for a library or open source project that provides UI for trimming videos as you see in the screenshot. Including

- Range selector with ability to increase, decrease and move the selection
- Thumbnails
- Current position of playback

Just the UI not the trimming itself.

If there is no ready solution available, then I'd like to now how to combine existing UI elements in a smart manner to achieve this or something similiar.

**Here is what I finally implemented:** [Range selector / range seekbar to trim video including thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598606/range-selector-range-seekbar-to-trim-video-including-thumbnails/48783823#comment63164349_36785834)

Comment: I always appreciate downvotes without comment.

Comment: you can use trimmer open source (https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer) which uses ffmpeg lib for video processing and it is best option for video  editing

Comment: I have tried it. It's not very stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this library will fit your needs.

[VideoTrimmer](https://github.com/knowledge4life/k4l-video-trimmer)

Comment: I installed the demo from https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3714 and I think you are right. Great! The lib also includes the mp4 trimmer! But unfortunately too late for my project ;(

Comment: @NikitaAxyonov can you help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801158/rangeseekbarview-how-to-select-a-fixed-range-frame-using-custom-rangeseekbarview please.

Comment: @Sagar , I am also stuck at showing the time frame of video being trimmed, have you found any solution with the Library mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: @B.shruti try this https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer library.it supports on android 10 as well

Answer (score 15):

I couldn't find a specific library, but you could use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the frames for the video specifying the exact time of the frame.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeInMiliSeconds * 1000,
                MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 14):

***You can get the UI from TELEGRAM (messaging app) source code available at GitHub***
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Activity: **VideoEditorActivity.java** (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/VideoEditorActivity.java)

Layout: **video_editor_layout.xml** (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/res/layout/video_editor_layout.xml)

***They have implemented their custom UI components VideoSeekBarView and VideoTimelineView.***

**VideoSeekBarView** (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Components/VideoSeekBarView.java)

**VideoTimelineView** (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Components/VideoTimelineView.java)

Attached is the **Telegram** VideoEditorActivity
[image]

Comment: Great screenshot! But GPL license ;( ;( ;(

Comment: this is the most promising solution. however, Due to the license I can't use it. If I'd try to get some ideas I'd probably and up copying the code;) I probably would reward the answer if the license would not be that strict.

Comment: @OneWorld did you find any solution for this ? It'd be great help I am searching for same :)

Comment: @Nisarg Hi! I initially thought about extracting the player code of the *Telegram project* into another app under GPL license and add some `Intent`s that other apps could broadcast to pass a video for trimming. However, meanwhile I created my own video trim activity using https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar. I dropped the requirement of thumbnails. It was still a lot of work! So, you could raise yourself a monument and go the way I initially planned and share it on github.

Comment: @OneWorld Thanks for your reply, I have completed trimming functionality using seekbar, It woks fine. I just need UI like above or something similar to whats app or instagram if you have any suggestion/idea else If I'll find anything will update you :)

Comment: Not sure what classes you are refering to and if you comply to their license.

Comment: @SagarHudge Hope [this](https://github.com/iknow4/Android-Video-Trimmer) helps , just found

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot for something similar without success. At the end I decided to stop the development of this feature.

But today, I found this [HERE](https://github.com/soverstas/Android--Two-Thumbs-Seekbar-for-Video-Cutter). I don't know if it's ok.

[image: desc]

**range selector**

[image]

**Current play position travels on the rangeselector after user clicked "play". However, you can't move play position.**

Another possibility is to read the source code of the official Android's application. I know that you are searching a library, but this can be another solution, and if you'll understand the google sourcecode you'll able to achieve the same quality of the Gallery application by Google.

Look here (Trim*.java classes): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-6.0.1_r31/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/

Sorry man, probably there isn't any opensource library to do that.
I hope that this two links could be useful for you.

Comment: tried it. worked OK. a little unstable. can't choose play position.

Answer (score 2):

**Try the following example on Git to trime video like whatsapp .**

this solution I have tried it's working perfectly this example includes the custom `RangeSeekBarView` , custom `ProgressBarView`with `seekbar` where you can select the video range of video you want trime and save to the destination

[VideoTrimming Like Whatsapp](https://github.com/HemendraGangwar/VideoTrimmingLikeWhatsapp)

Comment: I'm not working on that feature anymore. But it's probably worth looking at for other users!

Comment: @OneWorld I need help for this example ,I want to select maximum of `30s` from total duration but I am not able to figure out this please help if you have any idea any help will be accepted..plase

Comment: @Sagar are you serious? )) Just ask a new question or ask the author of the lib.

Comment: need some update for saving video, then it should work

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is best option 
if you are facing problem to compile ffmpeg use this link https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android  and follow commands from 
https://github.com/antpersan/CutVideoAndroid and for range Seekbar https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar or use shanrais suggested VideoSeekBarView

Comment: I don't look for trimming itselft. Just the UI. I already found a 2 thumbs rangebar for myself that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[**Media-for-mobile**](https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile)

**Video processing Library**

**Functions**

- Transcode video
- Join Video
- Cut Video
- Video Effect
- Audio Effect
- Get Media File Info
- Time Scaling
- List item

You can use its function by customizing your interface.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all  for your help,  i think to do that  with  c++ native code,  i am not  a  professional on it,  but  still  the  best  way  to  dealing  with  the  UI especially  when  we  have to create  a  professional  timeline, for confirmation,  the ffmpeg is  one of the best libraries https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg to edit videos on android,