# RangeSeekBarView how to select a fixed range frame using custom RangeSeekBarView

Tags: android, video-processing, rangeseekbar

I am using following code to select the range of video to `Trime` but I want select only part of `30s` from total duration `(2:30)` like `Whatsapp` is doing.

Referring to example:

[click here for example](https://github.com/HemendraGangwar/VideoTrimmingLikeWhatsapp)

> following is my custom class designed for `RangeSeekBarView`

```
 public class LeftRightRangeSeekBarView extends View {

private static final String TAG = LeftRightRangeSeekBarView.class.getSimpleName();
private int mHeightTimeLine;
private List<ThumbObjectClass> mThumbs;
private List<OnRangeSeekBarListener> mListeners;
private float mMaxWidth;
private float mThumbWidth;
private float mThumbHeight;
private int mViewWidth;
private float mPixelRangeMin;
private float mPixelRangeMax;
private float mScaleRangeMax;
private boolean mFirstRun;

private final Paint mShadow = new Paint();
private final Paint mLine = new Paint();

public LeftRightRangeSeekBarView(@NonNull Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public LeftRightRangeSeekBarView(@NonNull Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mThumbs = ThumbObjectClass.initThumbs(getResources());
    mThumbWidth = ThumbObjectClass.getWidthBitmap(mThumbs);
    mThumbHeight = ThumbObjectClass.getHeightBitmap(mThumbs);
    mScaleRangeMax = 100;
    mHeightTimeLine = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.frames_video_height);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mFirstRun = true;
    int shadowColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.shadow_color);
    mShadow.setAntiAlias(true);
    mShadow.setColor(shadowColor);
    mShadow.setAlpha(177);
    int lineColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.line_color);
    mLine.setAntiAlias(true);
    mLine.setColor(lineColor);       
}
public void initMaxWidth() {
    mMaxWidth = mThumbs.get(1).getPos() - mThumbs.get(0).getPos();
    onSeekStop(this, 0, mThumbs.get(0).getVal());
    onSeekStop(this, 1, mThumbs.get(1).getVal());
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int minW = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
    mViewWidth = resolveSizeAndState(minW, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
    int minH = getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop() + (int) mThumbHeight + mHeightTimeLine;
    int viewHeight = 0;
    viewHeight = resolveSizeAndState(minH, heightMeasureSpec, 1);
    setMeasuredDimension(mViewWidth, viewHeight);
    mPixelRangeMin = 0;
    mPixelRangeMax = mViewWidth - mThumbWidth;
    if (mFirstRun) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mThumbs.size(); i++) {
            ThumbObjectClass th = mThumbs.get(i);
            th.setVal(mScaleRangeMax * i);
            th.setPos(mPixelRangeMax * i);
        }          
        onCreate(this, currentThumb, getThumbValue(currentThumb));
        mFirstRun = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawShadow(canvas);
    drawThumbs(canvas);
}

private int currentThumb = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    final ThumbObjectClass mThumb;
    final ThumbObjectClass mThumb2;
    final float coordinate = ev.getX();
    final int action = ev.getAction();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {            
            currentThumb = getClosestThumb(coordinate);

            if (currentThumb == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            mThumb = mThumbs.get(currentThumb);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-down-" + coordinate);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-1-" + mThumb);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-------------------");
            mThumb.setLastTouchX(coordinate);
            onSeekStart(this, currentThumb, mThumb.getVal());
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

            if (currentThumb == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            mThumb = mThumbs.get(currentThumb);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-down-" + mThumb.getVal());
            Log.e("coordinate", "-2-" + mThumb);
            onSeekStop(this, currentThumb, mThumb.getVal());
            Log.e("coordinate", "-------------------");
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            Log.e("coordinate", "-ACTION_MOVE-" + currentThumb);
            mThumb = mThumbs.get(currentThumb);
            mThumb2 = mThumbs.get(currentThumb == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-mThumb22-" + mThumb);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-mThumb2dd-" + mThumb2);
            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = coordinate - mThumb.getLastTouchX();
            final float newX = mThumb.getPos() + dx;

            Log.e("coordinate", "-dx-" + dx);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-newX-" + newX);
            Log.e("coordinate", "-------------------");

            if (currentThumb == 0) {

                if ((newX + mThumb.getWidthBitmap()) >= mThumb2.getPos()) {
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-newpos-" + (mThumb2.getPos() - mThumb.getWidthBitmap()));
                    mThumb.setPos(mThumb2.getPos() - mThumb.getWidthBitmap());
                } else if (newX <= mPixelRangeMin) {
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-mPixelRangeMin-" + mPixelRangeMin);

                    mThumb.setPos(mPixelRangeMin);
                } else {
                    //Check if thumb is not out of max width

                    checkPositionThumb(mThumb, mThumb2, dx, true);
                    // Move the object
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-mThumb.getPos()+dx-" + (mThumb.getPos() + dx));

                    mThumb.setPos(mThumb.getPos() + dx);

                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                    mThumb.setLastTouchX(coordinate);
                }
                Log.e("coordinate", "-------------------");

            } else {

                if (newX <= mThumb2.getPos() + mThumb2.getWidthBitmap()) {
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-second-elese" + (mThumb2.getPos() + mThumb.getWidthBitmap()));

                    mThumb.setPos(mThumb2.getPos() + mThumb.getWidthBitmap());
                } else if (newX >= mPixelRangeMax) {
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-second-mPixelRangeMax" + mPixelRangeMax);

                    mThumb.setPos(mPixelRangeMax);
                } else {
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-second-mPixelRangeMax" + (mThumb.getPos() + dx));
                    Log.e("coordinate", "-second-lasttouch" + coordinate);

                    //Check if thumb is not out of max width
                    checkPositionThumb(mThumb2, mThumb, dx, false);
                    // Move the object
                    mThumb.setPos(mThumb.getPos() + dx);
                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                    mThumb.setLastTouchX(coordinate);
                }
                Log.e("coordinate", "-------------------");

            }

            setThumbPos(currentThumb, mThumb.getPos());

            // Invalidate to request a redraw
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void checkPositionThumb(@NonNull ThumbObjectClass mThumbLeft, @NonNull ThumbObjectClass mThumbRight, float dx, boolean isLeftMove) {

    if (isLeftMove && dx < 0) {
        if ((mThumbRight.getPos() - (mThumbLeft.getPos() + dx)) > mMaxWidth) {
            mThumbRight.setPos(mThumbLeft.getPos() + dx + mMaxWidth);
            setThumbPos(1, mThumbRight.getPos());
        }
    } else if (!isLeftMove && dx > 0) {
        if (((mThumbRight.getPos() + dx) - mThumbLeft.getPos()) > mMaxWidth) {
            mThumbLeft.setPos(mThumbRight.getPos() + dx - mMaxWidth);
            setThumbPos(0, mThumbLeft.getPos());
        }
    }
}

private int getUnstuckFrom(int index) {
    int unstuck = 0;
    float lastVal = mThumbs.get(index).getVal();
    for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ThumbObjectClass th = mThumbs.get(i);
        if (th.getVal() != lastVal)
            return i + 1;
    }
    return unstuck;
}

private float pixelToScale(int index, float pixelValue) {
    float scale = (pixelValue * 100) / mPixelRangeMax;
    if (index == 0) {
        float pxThumb = (scale * mThumbWidth) / 100;
        return scale + (pxThumb * 100) / mPixelRangeMax;
    } else {
        float pxThumb = ((100 - scale) * mThumbWidth) / 100;
        return scale - (pxThumb * 100) / mPixelRangeMax;
    }
}

private float scaleToPixel(int index, float scaleValue) {
    float px = (scaleValue * mPixelRangeMax) / 100;
    if (index == 0) {
        float pxThumb = (scaleValue * mThumbWidth) / 100;
        return px - pxThumb;
    } else {
        float pxThumb = ((100 - scaleValue) * mThumbWidth) / 100;
        return px + pxThumb;
    }
}

private void calculateThumbValue(int index) {
    if (index < mThumbs.size() && !mThumbs.isEmpty()) {
        ThumbObjectClass th = mThumbs.get(index);
        th.setVal(pixelToScale(index, th.getPos()));
        onSeek(this, index, th.getVal());
    }
}

private void calculateThumbPos(int index) {
    if (index < mThumbs.size() && !mThumbs.isEmpty()) {
        ThumbObjectClass th = mThumbs.get(index);
        th.setPos(scaleToPixel(index, th.getVal()));
    }
}

private float getThumbValue(int index) {
    return mThumbs.get(index).getVal();
}

public void setThumbValue(int index, float value) {
    mThumbs.get(index).setVal(value);
    calculateThumbPos(index);
    // Tell the view we want a complete redraw
    invalidate();
}

private void setThumbPos(int index, float pos) {
    mThumbs.get(index).setPos(pos);
    calculateThumbValue(index);
    // Tell the view we want a complete redraw
    invalidate();
}

private int getClosestThumb(float coordinate) {
    int closest = -1;
    if (!mThumbs.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mThumbs.size(); i++) {
            // Find thumb closest to x coordinate
            final float tcoordinate = mThumbs.get(i).getPos() + mThumbWidth;
            if (coordinate >= mThumbs.get(i).getPos() && coordinate <= tcoordinate) {
                closest = mThumbs.get(i).getIndex();
            }
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

private void drawShadow(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    if (!mThumbs.isEmpty()) {

        for (ThumbObjectClass th : mThumbs) {
            if (th.getIndex() == 0) {
                final float x = th.getPos() + getPaddingLeft();
                if (x > mPixelRangeMin) {
                    Rect mRect = new Rect((int) mThumbWidth, 0, (int) (x + mThumbWidth), mHeightTimeLine);
                    canvas.drawRect(mRect, mShadow);
                }
            } else {
                final float x = th.getPos() - getPaddingRight();
                if (x < mPixelRangeMax) {
                    Rect mRect = new Rect((int) x, 0, (int) (mViewWidth - mThumbWidth), mHeightTimeLine);
                    canvas.drawRect(mRect, mShadow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void drawThumbs(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

    if (!mThumbs.isEmpty()) {
        for (ThumbObjectClass th : mThumbs) {
            if (th.getIndex() == 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(th.getBitmap(), th.getPos() + getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() + mHeightTimeLine, null);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(th.getBitmap(), th.getPos() - getPaddingRight(), getPaddingTop() + mHeightTimeLine, null);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addOnRangeSeekBarListener(OnRangeSeekBarListener listener) {

    if (mListeners == null) {
        mListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    mListeners.add(listener);
}

private void onCreate(LeftRightRangeSeekBarView rangeSeekBarView, int index, float value) {
    if (mListeners == null)
        return;

    for (OnRangeSeekBarListener item : mListeners) {
        item.onCreate(rangeSeekBarView, index, value);
    }
}

private void onSeek(LeftRightRangeSeekBarView rangeSeekBarView, int index, float value) {
    if (mListeners == null)
        return;

    for (OnRangeSeekBarListener item : mListeners) {

        item.onSeek(rangeSeekBarView, index, value);
    }
}

private void onSeekStart(LeftRightRangeSeekBarView rangeSeekBarView, int index, float value) {
    if (mListeners == null)
        return;

    for (OnRangeSeekBarListener item : mListeners) {

        item.onSeekStart(rangeSeekBarView, index, value);
    }
}

private void onSeekStop(LeftRightRangeSeekBarView rangeSeekBarView, int index, float value) {

    if (mListeners == null)
        return;

    for (OnRangeSeekBarListener item : mListeners) {
        item.onSeekStop(rangeSeekBarView, index, value);
    }
}

public List<ThumbObjectClass> getThumbs() {
    return mThumbs;
}}
```